# Why is absolute positioning not working in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a SearchBar component that I need to appear over the ScrollView component towards the top of the screen (under the header).  Currently, it is not appearing on top even though I have it absolutely positioned and top: 0 set on it.  Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Here is the render:

```
    render() {
    const {isLoading, products} = this.props.products;

    if (isLoading) {
        return <Loader isVisible={true}/>;
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
                <ProductsContainer data={{productsList: { results: products }}}/>
            </ScrollView>
            <SearchBar style={styles.searchBar}/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Here are the styles:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
wrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    position: 'relative'
},
searchBar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0
},
scrollView: {
    position: 'relative'
}
```

});

Here is how it currently looks in my app:

[image]

Here is what it looks like when I swap the order of the ScrollView and SearchBar components:

[image]

End result once I can get the absolute positioning working:

[image]

Here is my SearchBar code:

```
render() {
        const myIcon = (<Icon name="search" size={30} style={styles.searchIcon}/>);
        const slidersIcon = (<Icon name="sliders" size={30} style={styles.slidersIcon}/>);

        return (
            <View style={styles.searchBar}>

                <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
                    <View>
                        {slidersIcon}
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.search}>
                        <View style={styles.searchSection}>
                            {myIcon}
                            <TextInput
                                style={styles.input}
                                placeholder="Search"
                                placeholderTextColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"
                                onChangeText={(searchString) => {
                                    this.setState({searchString})
                                }}
                                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                                editable={true}
                                autoCorrect={false}
                                autoFocus={false}
                                autoCaptialize={'none'}
                                autoCorrect={false}
                                onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
                                enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
                                onFocus={() => this.onFocus()}
                                onBlur={() => this.onBlur()}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
                {this.renderSearches()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const {products} = state;
    return {
        products
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SearchBar);

SearchBar.propTypes = {
    suggestions: PropTypes.array,
    value: PropTypes.string,
    onChangeText: PropTypes.func,
    suggestionsWrapperStyle: PropTypes.any,
    suggestionStyle: PropTypes.any,
    suggestionTextStyle: PropTypes.any,
    style: PropTypes.any,
    inputStyle: PropTypes.any
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({

    searchBar: {
        display: 'flex',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        shadowOpacity: 1,
        shadowOffset: {height: 2, width: 0},
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowRadius: 4,
        position: 'relative',
        height: 500,
        borderColor: 'green',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderWidth: 2,
        flexBasis: 100
    },

    searchContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        padding: 4
    },

    moreActions: {
        color: '#D6D6D6',
        paddingTop: 5,
        paddingBottom: 4,
        paddingLeft: 5,
        paddingRight: 6,
        borderColor: '#D6D6D6',
        borderRightWidth: 1
    },
    search: {
        marginLeft: 5,
        paddingTop: 5,
        paddingBottom: 4,
        paddingLeft: 5,
        paddingRight: 5,
        flex: 1

    },
    searchInput: {
        color: '#000',
        height: '10%'
    },
    searchSection: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        width: '100%'
    },
    searchIcon: {
        padding: 10,
        color: '#D6D6D6',
        fontSize: 14
    },
    slidersIcon: {
        padding: 10,
        color: '#D6D6D6',
        fontSize: 14
    },
    input: {
        flex: 2,
        paddingTop: 2,
        paddingRight: 10,
        paddingBottom: 2,
        paddingLeft: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        color: '#424242',
        width: '100%'
    },
});
```

Comment: Try swapping the order of your `ScrollView` and `SearchBar` within the `View` tag.

Comment: I just did but all it did was move the SearchBar to the top above the ScrollView but not on top of it (overlaying).  I have edited my question to include a screen I just took to show this.

Comment: Can you explain "overlaying" a bit more? Do you mean you want it to be transparent, or just take up a small bit at the top of the screen like in many apps?

Comment: Ok I just added another image to my question, which shows what I mean.  Here is another example:  http://dawnsbrain.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/css-layers-01.gif

Comment: I try to reproduce it with simple views and everything work well. Are you sur that your SearchBar component is override by your style props ?

Comment: I thought that so I removed the wrapper and container styles from my SearchBar component earlier but it still wouldn't appear right.  I have edited my question and attached my SearchBar code.  Please let me know if you see something wrong!

Comment: That's it i think. Your top View in the SearchBar component has a flex style, you didn't apply your absolute styles. It's a prop. You should get it and use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first render :

```
     <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
            <ProductsContainer data={{productsList: { results: products }}}/>
        </ScrollView>
        <SearchBar style={styles.searchBar}/>
    </View>
```

Your searchbar component render should be like this :

```
        <View style={[{styles.searchBar}, this.props.style]}>
            {some content}
        </View>
```

You apply the styles from your first render on the child. Because for the moment only the styles.searchBar are apply so there is no absolute there.

Comment: Oh that did it!!  For a second I forgot I had swapped the order of my ScrollView and SearchBar components but I just switched them back and its floating on top now!  Thank you so much